# How to delivery content (video) by download with python sdk?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services, azure-python-sdk

i'm a python developer, inexperienced in microsoft azure services.

For a client I have to allow downloading of videos using the azure media service (video streaming). I did find information on the subject in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-asset-download), but I want to get there using python (so either the rest azure api, or the python sdk).

I'm starting to believe it's impossible.

I need your help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need to do should be completely possible with the Python SDK.

I do not recommend using the REST API directly! It does not have any built in retry policies that Azure Resource Management API requires. You can get into issues with that in production - unless you know what you are doing and roll your own retry logic.

Use the official Python SDK client for Media Services only.

Also, the link above for the REST API is pointing to the legacy v2 API - do not use that now.  Use the latest v3 SDK client only here -

pip install azure-mgmt-media

We have a limited number of Python samples up here that show how to use the client SDK for Python - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-python

None of us on the team are Python experts, and we don't seem to get a lot of contributions to that repo - so it is not anywhere near as comprehensive as our .NET samples here - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet

But keep in mind that all the Azure SDK's are just auto generated off the REST API Swagger (Open API) - so they all use the exact same entities, and use the same JSON structure on the wire - so if you know what the REST API is doing and what the Entites are - you can easily port things around between languages.  Helps to know Python first though!

You mentioned you want to download stuff - that will require the use of the Storage SDKs for python.  Media Services just uses Azure Storage accounts. Meaning you can access the containers using SAS URl's to upload and download stuff.  Look at the Storage samples for Python to see what to do there. https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded video are stored as an **Assest file** if the files are uploaded using **Azure Media Services SDK**. which will make it easier to stream video to different devices.

To stream or download an asset, you first need to "**publish**" it by creating a locator. Locators provide access to files contained in the asset.

Media Services supports two types of locators:

1. OnDemandOrigin locators, used to stream media (for example, MPEG DASH, HLS, or Smooth Streaming)
2. Access Signature (SAS) locators, used to download media files.

Once you create the locators, you can build the URLs that are used to stream or download your files.

Here's a guide for doing that using **Rest API** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-rest-get-started

**Note :** you're uploading your videos directly to Azure Storage? If that's the case, instead of uploading your videos directly to Azure Storage, my suggestion would be to upload your videos using the **Azure Media Services SDK**

Azure Media Services has pretty good documentation which might help with your other asks: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/media-services/resources/